# Deserialize Simple Array Of String from REST to List<String> in java

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the JSON from  frontend angular to API and trying to convert array of string to list of string in controller :

```
GET : http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/health/getValues

{
    "page" : 2,
    "size" : 10,
    "assignedTo" : [ "user1@example.com", "user2@example.com" ],
    "status" : ["abc","def"]
}
```

I am trying to convert first into List in following way but unable to access it in @Rest:

```
public class SearchDTO {
    @JsonProperty("page")
     public int page;

    @JsonProperty("size")
    public int size;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class AssignedTo {
        private String assignedTo;
        @JsonCreator
        public AssignedTo(@JsonProperty("assignedTo") String assignedTo) {
            this.assignedTo = assignedTo;
        }
  }
    @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Status {
        private String status;
        @JsonCreator
        public Status(@JsonProperty("status") String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
        }

    @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class LogType {
        private String logType;
        @JsonCreator
        public LogType(@JsonProperty("logType") String logType) {
            this.logType = logType;
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to access same in the @RestController Class

```
@PostMapping(path = "getValue", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ListDTO> getAll(@RequestBody SearchDTO searchMapping ){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(logPageSearchService.getLogs(searchMapping.page,
                logSearchMapping.size,// other variables here
                ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple dto class remove json tag it will work

```
@RestController
class DemoController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/getValue", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<SearchDTO> getAll(@RequestBody SearchDTO searchMapping ){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(searchMapping);
    }

}

class SearchDTO {
    public int page;
    public int size;
    public String[] assignedTo;
    public String[] status;
    
    // getters / setters
}
```

Comment: Even more better to use `private List<String> assignedTo;` and `private List<String> status;` in DTO.